# Writing to an excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel, oledb

I am trying to add variable values in WinAutomation into a spreadsheet by column header for every row that doesn't have a value. I've tried two different methods (insert into and update). I am getting the following error: "Runtime Error: Error in SQL Statement: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." Does anyone see something that I did wrong here that is causing said error?

```
INSERT INTO [Sheet1$]
[SAP Employee ID] VALUES(%SapEmployeeNumber%)
WHERE RowNumber IS null


UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET
([SAP Employee ID] = %SapEmployeeNumber%
,[Concur Travel] = %CreditOrOutofPocket%
,[Participant Name] = %ParticipantName%
,[Participant Birth Date] = %ParticipantBirth%
,[Work Location] = %ParticipantWorkLocation%
,[Street Address] = %ParticipantStreetAddress%
,[City] = %ParticipantCity%
,[State] = %ParticipantState%
,[Zip] = %ParticipantZip%
,[Participant Email] = %ParticipantEmail%
,[Contact Phone] = %ParticipantContactPhone%
,[Credit Card Profile] = %ParticipantCreditProfile%
,[Credit Limit] = %ParticipantCreditLimit% )
WHERE
[SAP Employee ID] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Is this your full query? There is no insert

Comment: There's already a templated excel sheet that i'm trying to update. I did think about going the insert into route instead.